# App actions are working using AATP(App Action Testing Tools) but not working from google assistant

Tags: java, android, google-assistant-sdk, app-actions

I have done the below steps:

Step 1) Create action.xml with Built-In Intent and defined in androidmanifest.xml

Step 2) Create a deep link through firebase dynamic link SDK

Step 3) Map the Deeplink with built-in Intent in android action.xml

Step 4) Create the application in Playstore

Step 5) Upload the signed APK in Playstore as save in draft

Step 6) Open the app action testing tool from the latest android studio after uploading the APK to the play store

Step 7) log in to the same google account in the play store, android studio, and android device

Step 8) Make sure the check the same Locale language (en-Us) in Android device and action testing tool.

It's working fine in APP Action Testing Tools But not working in Google Assistant.

I have deployed action in the google assistant console as well.

Google assistant opening conversation panel inside google assistant but not the opening application.

Comment: Android isn't familiar territory for me, I've only ever written one production android app.  However, I'd like more explanation at the top / before step one about what platform and what you are doing.  I can google search for `action.xml`, but off the top of my head, I'm not even sure where that fits in the Android framework.  (Note: `app-actions` only has 74 followers so I think a bit of explanation could help I know there are a lot more Android devs than that)

Comment: Also.  "It's not working" is never a helpful error description.  Please explain exactly the error message you are getting or the problem behavior / symptoms you are experiencing.  (Describe both expected behavior and actual behavior is typical for bugs)

Comment: It could be related to multiple things. You can narrow it down using this [checklist](https://developers.google.com/assistant/app/troubleshoot#test_5). Can you try it?